# C/Python binding: pointer address modification

Tags: python, c++, ctypes, language-binding

### Source

**C++**

```
extern "C"
{
    Service* create_service( int port )
    {
        Settings settings;
        settings.set_port( port );

        auto service = new Service( settings );

        std::cout << "create_service returning pointer address: " << service << std::endl;

        return service;
    }

    void release_service( Service* service )
    {
        std::cout << "release_service consuming pointer address: " << service << std::endl;
        delete service;
    }
}
```

**Python**

```
from ctypes import *

library = cdll.LoadLibrary('distribution/library/libhelpers.dylib')

class Service(object):
    def __init__(self, port):
        self.obj = library.create_service(port)
        print "__init__ address: ", self.obj

    def __del__(self):
        print "__del__", self.obj
        library.release_service(self.obj);
```

### Console

> create_service returning pointer address: 0x7fc3a0e330e0
>
> **init** address: -1595723552
>
> **del** address: -1595723552
>
> release_service consuming pointer address: 0xffffffffa0e330e0
>
> Segmentation fault: 11

### Error

> Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
>
> Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0xffffffff914d37a0

### Build (cmake)

> set( CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER clang++ )
>
> set( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -Weffc++ -pedantic" )
>
> add_library( helpers SHARED ${MANIFEST} )
>
> target_link_libraries( helpers restbed )

### Description

When returning a C++ class instance as a pointer.  Python receives the correct address. However when using this address at a later date, it appears to have been modified.

Comment: Why are you returning a local variable?

Comment: It has been allocated on the heap.  The assumption is this would be acceptable?

Comment: "Python receives the correct address" - you haven't demonstrated that in what you show above.

Comment: `Settings settings;` is not on the heap.

Comment: @Mat I've updated with additional logging showing the address status when in the Python environment.

Comment: @doctorlove: settings isn't being returned. (If `Service` hold on to a reference to that parameter rather than taking a copy (or just using it in the constructor without holding on to it), would be a problem, but I don't think that would change anything to the question here.)

Comment: @Corvusoft: what you're printing from python is "truncated" already, you're missing the top 32 bits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears I was giving insufficient context to ctypes.

```
from ctypes import *

library = cdll.LoadLibrary('distribution/library/libhelpers.dylib')

class Service(object):
    def __init__(self, port):
        library.create_service.restype = c_void_p
        self.obj = library.create_service(port)

    def __del__(self):
        library.release_service.argtypes = [c_void_p]
        library.release_service(self.obj);
```

Comment: ctypes defaults to C `int` for integers, which, as you discovered, truncates a 64-bit pointer. You can use `CDLL` directly instead of `cdll.LoadLibrary`. `cdll` is meant for Windows, such as `cdll.msvcrt`. BTW, the typical tag for Python ctypes is just "ctypes", not "python-ctypes".

Comment: You should move setting `restype` and `argtypes` out of the method definitions. There's no point in redefining them for the single library instance each time you init/deallocate a `Service` object.