# ctypes: pointer address modification when using lib.so (on Mac) but not when using lib.dll (on Windows)

Tags: python, c++, windows, macos, ctypes

## Source

### C++

```
/*** type define class template for extern "C" ***/
typedef Mpoly<double> MpolyDouble;

// Declare functions as extern "C" for ctypes
//
// >> compiler statement (mac/linux): g++ -shared -o libPoly.so -fPIC libPoly.cpp
// >> compiler statement (windows): g++ -shared -o libPoly.dll libPoly.cpp
//
extern "C" {

    /*** libPoly Constructor/Destructor Routines ***/
    MpolyDouble* Poly_new(int size, int dim) { return new(nothrow) MpolyDouble(size,dim); }
    void Poly_del(MpolyDouble* foo)  { delete foo; }

    /*** libPoly Miscellaneous Routines ***/
    void PolyPrint(MpolyDouble* foo) {

        // print out address of object pointer
        std::cout << "address of foo: " << foo << std::endl; 

        // call MpolyDouble.print() method
        foo->print(); 
    }
}
```

### Python

```
#*** import python libraries ***#
from ctypes import *
from numpy.ctypeslib import ndpointer
import numpy as np
import weakref

#**************************************#
#*** load the libPoly shared object ***#
#**************************************#
lib = CDLL('./libPoly.so')      #! for Mac/Linux
#lib = CDLL('./libPoly.dll')    #! for Windows

#********************************************************#
#*** set the argument types for each member attribute ***#
#********************************************************#
## Poly_new
lib.Poly_new.argtypes = [c_int, c_int]
lib.Poly_new.restype  = c_void_p
## Poly_del
lib.Poly_del.argtypes  = [c_void_p] #<---edit
lib.Poly_del.restype  = None
## PolyPrint
lib.PolyPrint.argtypes = [c_void_p] #<---edit
lib.PolyPrint.restype = None

#********************************************************#
#***            define a python class Poly            ***#
#********************************************************#
class Poly(object):

    # GHV Instantiation Routine:
    def __init__(self,size=1,dim=2):
        # ensure that the input args are of correct type
        size = int(size)
        dim = int(dim)

        # call the C/C++ function
        self.obj = lib.Poly_new(size,dim)

    def __del__(self):
        lib.Poly_del(self.obj)
        self._obj = None

    # GHV Print Routine:
    def Print(self):
        print 'address of self.obj',hex(id(self.obj))
        # call the C/C++ function
        lib.PolyPrint(self.obj)
```

## OS X (Sample) Implementation

### Terminal

> $ python
>
> from PolyWrapper import *
>
> P = Poly()
>
> P.Print()

### Terminal Output

> address of self.obj 0x10038fc08
>
> address of foo: 0x1804810
>
> Segmentation fault: 11

### Console

> Process:               python2.7 [3359]
>
> Path:                  /Users/USER/*/python2.7
>
> Identifier:            python2.7
>
> Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
>   Parent Process:        bash [3341]
>   Responsible:           Terminal [235]
>
> Date/Time:             2016-02-16 12:48:22.220 -0500
>   OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.11.3 (15D21)
>
> Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
>
> Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000001804810

## Description

### Question

Why does this work on my windows platform but not anywhere else?

I do not get any compiler errors on either platform. Also, my use to the typedef to get past the function template has not given me problems on other similar projects.

### Possible Clues

- Notice that the 'address of foo', printed from within the .cpp file is the same address that is raising the alarm in the console 'Exception Codes'. Is python receiving the correct address when creating a new object? How to tell, and how is that possible?
- A similar issue was reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20444297/c-python-binding-pointer-address-modification), but I don't believe this is the problem here, because I have explicitly set `restype`, `argtype`, and `argtypes`.
- `g++ --version` -- `Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)` (OS X) and `g++ (GCC) 2.9.3` (Windows CygWIN). If you think compilers might be the issue just note that I used this same compiler to generate both a lib.so and lib.dll. Execution from Spyder (Python (x,y)) works; execution from CygWIN shell for the lib.so gives the SIG11.

Comment: It should be `lib.Poly_del.argtypes  = [c_void_p]`, not `lib.Poly_del.argtype  = c_void_p`.

Comment: Also `id(self.obj)` has nothing to do with anything seen by C. In CPython that's the address of the Python object, which is just a Python `int` because the `c_void_p` getfunc converts the pointer value.

Comment: why would that matter for the Poly_del argtypes? Also, I agree with you about the id(self.obj) not being associated with C, as I found out!

Comment: `self.obj` is the address of the C++ object as a Python integer. If you don't set `argtypes` it uses the default conversion to a C `int`, which truncates the pointer to a 32-bit value. If you don't want to set `argtypes`, though I suggest you do, then you need to wrap the pointer value as `self.obj = c_void_p(lib.Poly_new(size, dim))`.

Comment: Thank for the feedback. I implemented the `c_void_p` way. Can you clarify what you meant by not setting the argstypes? Running this gives me the following Traceback: `Exception AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has not attribute 'Poly_del' in <bound method Poly.__del__ of <__main__.Poly object at addr>> ignored"`

Comment: If I set `lib.Poly_new.restypes  = [c_void_p]`, I get a sig11. So I take it you mean to set all lib routines that receive a `MpolyDouble*` to `lib.*.argtypes = [c_void_p]`. This also gives me a sig11 unless I use `self.obj = c_void_p(lib.Poly_new(size, dim))`, which then still throws the lib-type-none error above

Comment: You need a certain attention to detail here since these function pointers have a dict that lets you set arbitrary attributes. It's `lib.Poly_new.restype = c_void_p`. The `argtypes` (note: plural) attribute is a list of types for converting the function arguments. The `restype` (note: singular) attribute is the type used for the result, and if you set a simple type such as `c_void_p` or `c_char_p`, ctypes will automatically convert the result to a regular Python type such as `int`, `str`, etc.

Comment: Assigning `restype` is required to properly handle pointer results in a 64-bit process. Setting `argtypes` is optional if you manually wrap integer pointer values with `c_void_p`, but I recommend setting it to get some measure of type safety for arguments. An `ArgumentError` is more friendly in Python programming than crashing the process with a segfault.

Comment: Okay, @eryksun, I've made two edits to the original post to modify `lib.Poly_del.argtypes` and `lib.PolyPrint.argtypes`, which I believe is what you are suggesting. Sorry, I'm a little slow today.

I still get an error at `lib.Poly_del(self.obj)` due to the library apparently not being in scope. Is this a separate error or am I still miss-understanding?

Comment: `__del__` shouldn't reference globals since they get cleared during interpreter teardown. As a workaround you can add a `_lib` class attribute and reference `self._lib` or just use a local reference from a default argument value: `def __del__(self, Poly_del=lib.Poly_del)`. I would also add a class attribute `_obj = None`. Then in `__init__`, assign `self._obj` (note: underscore), which overrides the class attribute. Then in `__del__` only call `Poly_del` if `self._obj is not None` and also execute `del self._obj` to restore the class attribute value of None.

Comment: @eryksun, thanks for all your help! I now have a version that runs properly on all my workstations. In the end, I did implement both _obj and _ as class attributes. I also currently have `self._obj = c_void_p(lib.Poly_new(size, dim))` within `__init__` (and other routines that pass out a pointer to my c++ object's).

Comment: correction: "_obj and _lib"

Comment: You can add an answer that details your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my final solution. I made no significant changes on the c++ side of things - only the Python ctypes bindings. I also added some logic to handle the importing of dynamic library (shared object), which is not general. It works for my two workstations and a few others that I have to collaborate with the exception of a 32 bit version of Python2.7.

#### Lessons Learned:

- Pay attention to default bit lengths for numbers when using different platforms (Unix vs. Windows, 32 bit vs 64 bit, etc.).
- Take advantage of class attributes for: (i) good coding practices, and (ii) ensuring that a `__del__` routine can be easily linked to a c++ object's destructor routine, which is essential when passing objects back and forth as pointers.
- I made the mistake of calling `lib` as a global, which did not give me problems until evoking `__del__`; however, by the time `lib.Poly_del(self.obj)` was called, `lib` was no longer definded.

## Python bindings (PolyWrapper.py)

```
#*************************************#    
#***    import python libraries    ***#
#*************************************#
from ctypes import *
from numpy.ctypeslib import ndpointer
import numpy as np
import weakref
import platform

#**************************************#
#*** load the libPoly shared object ***#
#**************************************#
print.system()
if (platform.system() == "Windows" or platform.system() == "CYGWIN-6.1"):
    lib = CDLL('./libPoly.dll')
else:
    lib = CDLL('./libPoly.so')

#********************************************************#
#*** set the argument types for each member attribute ***#
#********************************************************#
## Poly_new
lib.Poly_new.argtypes  = [c_int, c_int]
lib.Poly_new.restype   = c_void_p
## Poly_del
lib.Poly_del.argtypes  = [c_void_p]
lib.Poly_del.restype   = None
## PolyPrint
lib.PolyPrint.argtypes = [c_void_p]
lib.PolyPrint.restype  = None

#********************************************************#
#***            define a python class Poly            ***#
#********************************************************#
class Poly(object):
    _obj = None
    _local = lib

    # Poly Instantiation Routine:
    def __init__(self,size=1,dim=1):
        # ensure that the input args are of correct type
        size = int(size)
        dim = int(dim)
        # call the C/C++ function
        self._obj = c_void_p(self._lib.Poly_new(size,dim))
    
    # Poly Destructor Routine:
    def __del__(self):
        if (self._obj is not None):
            self._lib.Poly_del(self._obj)
            del self._obj

    # Poly Print Routine:
    def Print(self):
        # call the C/C++ function
        self._lib.PolyPrint(self._obj)
```